# How to prevent Application Insights from formatting date strings

Tags: c#, appinsights

We are currently using the .Net Microsoft.ApplicationInsights package and sending some custom events to application insights. The problem is, that application insights is formatting date string.

We are sending the following data to Application Insights:

```
Application Insights Telemetry: 
"data": {
  "baseType": "EventData",
  "baseData":{
     "ver":2,
     "name":"RandomName",
     "properties": {
          "DeveloperMode":"true", 
          "startingDate":"2022-11-07", 
          ...some other properties 
 }}}}
```

(I have removed the unnecessary information)

Result in Application Insights:

`startingDate: 2022-11-07T00:00:00.0000000Z`

The custom properties (for example the startingDate) are included in a free string dictionary and it looks like that application insights recognizes the date string as a 'date' and changes its values behind the scenes.

Is there a way to tell application insights to **NOT** format the values we are sending?